# Problem in installing rgbdslam_freiburg

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I run the "rosmake rgbdslam_freiburg" command, the "../src/SiftGPU/SiftGPU.cpp:1181:18: error: ‘chdir’ was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [../../../build/siftgpu/SiftGPU.o] Error 1" error occurs, I don't know what's wrong with it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66734/problem-in-installing-rgbdslam_freiburg/) by [Mohsen.X55](https://answers.ros.org/users/5231/mohsen.x55/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mohsen.X55](https://answers.ros.org/users/5231/mohsen.x55/) on 2013-07-06**:
finally this messages appears: "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:123 (MESSAGE):
SiftGPU cannot be compiled.  Returned: 2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't reproduce this error.

Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340270/chdir-not-declared-compilation-error-g) helps (first hit on google when searching for the error message).

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can change  CMakeLists.txt  set(USE_SIFT_GPU        1)  -> set(USE_SIFT_GPU        0) .  you can try.

---

Originally posted by [NANZHE LI](https://answers.ros.org/users/18226/nanzhe-li/) with karma: 11 on 2014-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1